# c# How to allow some lower level forms to be acessible despite active form called by ShowDialog() method?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

i got application, it shows 3 forms: **log window**, **status window**, and **option window**, **option window** calls some other forms and some of these forms are required to be called using ***ShowDialog()*** to return dialog result value for further decision making.

Using ***ShowDialog()*** raises problem, cause form called by that method excluding other forms from being accessible.

So my problem is i would like to be able to make atleast **log window** accessible no matter how much other forms has been called. Is there a way to make **log window** to independent form other forms, or could it be taken over by form called as last?

***EDIT:***
I failed to mention that the behaviour provided by ***ShowDialog()*** is quite usefull in my app and that i only lack ability to free that one or two forms from being locked. Switching to ***Show()*** is not option I'm considering as best while other forms, that are parent to form called by ***ShowDialog()*** are required to be still locked.

Comment: Use `Show()` instead.

Comment: @Prix i cant i use ShowDialog() to return data back to parent form

Comment: I'm sure that returning data is not enough of a reason of not using `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @JoriO In fact it is not, the way ShowDialog() locks other forms and makes particular form on top with all focus, and disables all other forms, but in this case i need for some of these forms to be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I now modeled your situation and found solution:

1. Use `Show()` instead `ShowDialog()` for dialog.
2. Write some code in the dialog to close it window after press the button (Ok, Cancel etc.). Because auto-closing works with `ShowDialog` only. But you don't need to set `DialogResult` manually.
3. At the  Options form subscribe to `FormClosed` event to get `DialogResult`. For example:

   ```
   dlg.FormClosed += (o, a) => { this.Text = dlg.DialogResult.ToString(); };
   ```
4. Handle `Activate` event of Options form to prevent focusing on parent window when dialog is opened:

   ```
   if (dlg != null) dlg.Focus();
   ```

This solution has some difference with system behaviour of `ShowDialog`, but it works good.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make a choice between the two.

- Use `ShowDialog()`, so that your parent form pauses execution, and only resumes when the second form is closed, or
- Use `Show()`, so that your parent form continues execution after displaying the second form.

If you want to take some action, or read values from the second form when it's closed, then subscribe to its `Closed` event before you show it.

Let's assume your second form has a "First Name" TextBox, and a property to return that value:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return yourFirstNameTextBox.Text; }
}
```

In your first form, you can subscribe to an event to take some action when the event occurs, like this:

```
var f2 = new SecondForm();
f2.Closed += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(f2.FirstName);
f2.Show();
```

Now the user can continue on their way with both forms, and when the second form is closed, a message box will display the value of the "First Name" TextBox.

You'll probably want to do something more meaningful than this. Instead of displaying a message box, you could update a field on the first form, or take some any other action or set of actions that you want.

```
f2.Closed += (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(f2.FirstName);
        nameLabel.Text = f2.FirstName;
        // another action
        // yet another action
    };
```